# a search box with options relevant for a particular item that is selected django

Tags: python, django

Am having a search box, that i can use to search for items in django database and prints the results out at the template as a table.

Presently the code is working but i intend customizing the search, to accommodate a select tag so that whatever the user typed and and selected should query the database and fetch the outcome or result.

i tried but it not working

q is gotten from text input while x is gotten from select tag

here is my code:

```
def search_form(request):

    data = OrderItem.objects.order_by().values_list('certification_type', flat=True).distinct()
    print data

    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']

        print q

        x = request.GET['certification_type']
        print x

        items = OrderItem.objects.filter(Q(order_type__iexact=x and order_type__iexact=q) | Q(certification_type__iexact=x and certification_type__iexact=q) | Q(item__iexact=x and item__iexact=q)
         | Q(certification_no__iexact=x and certification_no__iexact=q) | Q(client__user__email__iexact=x and client__user__email__iexact=q) | Q(client__phone_number__iexact=x and client__phone_number__iexact=q)
         | Q(created_on__icontains=x and created_on__icontains=q))




        for x in items:
            for q in items:
                print items


        return render(request, 'i/search_results.html', {'items':items, 'q_query':q, 'x_query':x})
    else:
        return render(request, 'i/search_form.html', {'error':True,  "data":data})
```

Comment: @Leistungsabfall the edited copy seems not to work, coz am having syntax error at order_type__iexact=q

Comment: Are you sure the initial revision works? Because all I did was indenting your code.

Comment: the initial revision didn't work, it gave error at order_type__iexact=q         this is at =

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding [how lookups with Q objects work](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q).

Assuming you want to filter `OrderItem` objects by

1. occurrence of the **search string** `q` in any attribute
2. `certification_type` gotten from the **select tag** `x`

you could do the following:

```
items = OrderItem.objects.filter(
    certification_type=x,
    Q(order_type__iexact=q) |
    Q(item__iexact=q) |
    Q(certification_no__iexact=q) |
    Q(client__user__email__iexact=q) |
    Q(client__phone_number__iexact=q) |
    Q(created_on__icontains=q)
)
```